# How to pass data from viewmodel to view

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm-light

I have a windows phone 8.1 silverlight application, and I'm using MVVMLight toolkit.
I have three ViewModel: Main, PivotItem and Item.
In the MainViewModel I have an ObservableCollection of PivotItem, and in the PivotItemViewModel an ObservableCollection of ItemViewModel and finally in the ItemViewModel I have the properties for an item.

This is the MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="{Binding Title}" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItemViewModels}">
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LongListSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemViewModels}">
                        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tipus}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Megjegyzes}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                <commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectedCommand,
                                                                           Mode=OneWay}"
                                                         CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                                                                                    ElementName=LongListSelector}"
                                                         PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </phone:LongListSelector>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

And for the LongListSelector Tap event I want to pass the selected item to my EditView.

Here is my SelectedCommand in the PivotItemViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<ItemViewModel> SelectedCommand { get; set; }

private void Edit(ItemViewModel item)
        {

            ApplicationController.Default.NavigateTo(ViewType.Edit);            
        }

public PivotItemViewModel()
        {
            SelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<ItemViewModel>(Edit);
        }
```

My first question is which ViewModel should I use, PivotItemViemModel or ItemViewModel for the EditView's datacontext? And how do I pass the selected item to the view ?

Comment: You want pass the selected item from View to ViewModel, right?

Comment: Not exactly. It's already passed to the viewmodel, and I want to send it from the MainViewModel to the ItemViewModel and use it as the datacontext for my EditView. Altough I already solved it, I'm open to ideas becouse I don't like how I did it. I added another NavigateTo method with a parameter to my  NavigationService, and I use my GetNavigationData method to set the datacontext to the selected item.